# Doctrine 2.4 lezy loading loads assosiations on load in separate queries

Tags: doctrine-orm, associations, lazy-loading

I found strange queries in log and detected source:

```
echo app()->getCountSql(); // 2
$table->findAll();
echo app()->getCountSql(); // 21
```

$table is an autogenerated repository for page\route class

after loading routes doctrine loading page for each route in separate query.

i checked proxy genereation, i manualy created Proxy__CG__\page\page and Proxy__CG__\page\route objects and it works fine. I tested metadatas and in route assosiation "page" i found fetch = 2 (LEZY).

What can be reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

i've found answer in one of open doctrine bugs http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1390, i hope this can save some one few hours.